# viewmodel data not read before view is shown

Tags: json, vb.net, mvvm

During startup of an MVVM Prism WinStore 8.1 App project I load the ViewModel like in the HubApp Template. So I have a JSON file containing the information that should be shown on the tiles of the hub. When navigating to another page and returning back from that page to the HubPage, the tiles are not shown.
I have the impression that the View - navigating back from the PageStack - is shown BEFORE the ViewModel even has had the time to read it's JSON file again.

How can I force the View to wait until the ViewModel data has loaded?

Or even better: how can I save the statedata of the HubPage and retrieve it on returning to the HubPage . In that way, the data would not have to be read from the JSON file again.

I have NO TROUBLE binding data to the View, but as said, I think it has to do with time it takes re-reading the JSON file. Am I right? Other suggestions?

Regards

Comment: In the mean time I think I have found the most elegant solution that solves this: in the Prism library there is an option to add a <RestorabelState>  attribute to properties of ViewModels. This prevents the need to read the JSON file over again when navigated back to the HubPage.

Answer (score 1):

My best suggestion is that the related property in the ViewModel is given the 'RestorableState' annotation. so that it is kept between navigation from-and-back and read from memory once it has been read for a first time. From memory is the fastest thinkable way to get data back.